# C# DataGridView Automatically Adding One _Extra_ Row

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows, extra

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7 Professional 64]

I have a *C#* class that extends *DataGridView*:

```
public class DataGridViewTest : DataGridView
```

This class programatically sets the number of *columns* and *rows*.

I have a *Form* application that creates an instance of *DataGridViewTest* and adds it to a *GroupBox*.

*DataGridViewTest* defines static members for the number of *columns* and the number of *rows*:

```
private static int NUM_COLUMNS = 2;
private static int NUM_ROWS = 2;
```

Here is the code that sets everything up:

```
public DataGridViewTest()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.Name = "Column " + i.ToString();
        this.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

As you can see _NUM_ROWS_ is set to *2*.

When the application runs, however, the *DataGridViewTest*  shows a data grid with *3* rows, not *2*. (Similarly, setting NUM_ROWS to *0* creates a data grid with *1* row.)

Why is this *extra* row being added?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: DataGridView Extra Row]

Thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 3rd row is the for adding new rows. Set the property as follow:

> `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false`

Comment: Ahh!! That's simple enough... Thanks!